rangemode tozero not work for datetime format
I would like plotly plot xaxis start from 00:00:00. I try to use rangemode 'tozero` as below but it not work.
What's proper way to let the xaxis start from 00:00:00?
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np
import datetime

def save_fig(fig,width,height,pngname):
    fig.write_image(pngname,format="png", width=width, height=height, scale=1)
    print("[[%s]]"%pngname)
    #fig.show()
    return

def main():
    title = "bootchart startup time"
    xlabel = "Timestamp"
    ylabel = "Train"
    width = 800
    height = 400
    
    pngname = "/media/sf_work/demo.png"

    data = '''
name,start,end
A,5,10
B,7,10
C,4,10
'''

    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))#, delim_whitespace=True)
    for name in ['start','end']:
        df[name] = pd.to_datetime(df[name], unit='s')

    fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="start", x_end="end", y="name", color="name")
    layout = dict(
        title=title,
        xaxis_title=xlabel,
        yaxis_title=ylabel,
        title_x=0.5,   
        margin=dict(l=10,t=20,r=0,b=40),
        width=width,
        height=height,
        plot_bgcolor='#ffffff',#'rgb(12,163,135)',
      paper_bgcolor='#ffffff',        
        hoverlabel=dict(
            bgcolor="white",
            font_size=8,
            font_family="Rockwell"
        ),
        showlegend=False,
        xaxis=dict(
            rangemode="tozero",
            #autorange="reversed",
            tickmode='array',
            tickangle=-25,
            tickformat='%H:%M:%S',
            #tickvals = xvals,
            #ticktext= xtexts,
            showline=True,
            linecolor='black',
            linewidth=.5,
            ticks='outside',
            zeroline=True,
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            side='right',
            showline=False,
            linecolor='black',
            linewidth=.5,            
            showgrid=False,
            gridcolor='grey',
            gridwidth=.5,
        ),        
    )
    fig.update_layout(layout)
    save_fig(fig,width,height,pngname)
    return

main()




In this case, specify the desired start time and maximum data frame value in the x-axis range setting.
xaxis=dict(
    #rangemode="tozero",
    range=[datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0), df['end'].max()],# update
    #autorange="reversed",
    tickmode='array',
    tickangle=-25,
    tickformat='%H:%M:%S',
    #tickvals = xvals,
    #ticktext= xtexts,
    showline=True,
    linecolor='black',
    linewidth=.5,
    ticks='outside',
    zeroline=True,
),


